Did the STEREO spacecraft have coherent transponders for range-rate measurements for tracking and orbit predictions? If not, how were they tracked?
For this answer to STEREO-A/B conjunction I did a quick run for Stereo-B in Horizons and looked at the output.
*******************************************************************************
 Revised:  Feb 08, 2023             STEREO-B Spacecraft                    -235
                                http://stereo.gsfc.nasa.gov/
 NOTE: 
  Contact with STEREO-B was lost 2014-Oct-01. 

  After 22 months, contact was regained at 22:27 UTC on August 21, 2016, when 
  the Deep Space Network established a lock on STEREO-B for 2.4 hours. The
  trajectory here is updated to use that tracking data. 

  It has been determined the spacecraft is in an uncontrolled spin of 
  3 deg/second. 

  2023-Feb-08:
   There has been no contact or new tracking data since 2016, but an updated
   prediction was added to support a search effort.

  2017-Sep-20: 
   Fix did NOT occur. Last contact with the spacecraft was September 23, 2016.

  2016-Oct-14: 
   Another opportunity to potentially fix the spacecraft will not occur until 
   mid-2017. Once its computer is powered on there will be about two minutes 
   to upload the fix before STEREO-B enters failure mode again. 

  http://stereo-ssc.nascom.nasa.gov/behind_status.shtml

The 2.4 hour "lock" on August 21, 2016 seems long enough to get good range-rate tracking data from its coherent transponders, assuming that

The STEREO spacecraft HAVE coherent transponders (or some other mechanism for range-rate measurements) and
That's what a "lock" means.

In the beginning of the STEREO mission, it seems that precise tracking would have been important. From Does the arrow in this STEREO trajectory animation point heliocentric prograde, or towards the Sun? and Orbits of the two STEREO spacecraft:

But once in heliocentric orbits where the forces on the spacecrafts should be quite straight forward to integrate, perhaps the high precision of a coherent transponder would not be needed - all you need to know is where to point the DSN dish to start the next search.
So I'd like ot ask:
Question: Did the STEREO spacecraft have coherent transponders for range-rate measurements for tracking and orbit predictions? If not, how were they tracked such that state vector ephemerides could be produced?
From https://www.eoportal.org/satellite-missions/stereo#spacecraft

In addition to normal data transmissions, the two STEREO spacecraft also broadcast continuously a low-rate (~600 bit/s) set of data consisting of typically 1 minute summaries (or 5 minute in the case of SECCHI) to be used for space weather forecasting, much like is currently done with the ACE and SOHO data. Several participating NOAA and international ground tracking stations will collect the data and send it electronically to the SSC (STEREO Science Center) at GSFC where it will be processed into useful physical quantities and be placed onto the STEREO website (http://stereo.gsfc.nasa.gov/). The goal is to have the processed data available within 5 minutes of receipt at the tracking stations. 16) 17)

From https://www.eoportal.org/satellite-missions/stereo#stereo-mission-operations

FDF (Flight Dynamics Facility): The FDF at the NASA GSFC determines the orbits of the observatory from tracking data provided by the DSN ground stations, and it generates predicted DSN station contact periods and predicted and definitive orbit data products. The FDF also generates orbital ephemeris data in support of orbit maneuvers that satisfy science and mission requirements, and it transfers this information to the STEREO MOC via the FDF Products Center.

STEREO Science Operations Plan, Version 2.0, November 9, 2009 does not seem to specify one way or the other either, if I'm reading it correctly.

related: What are the differences (if any) between the techniques of range-rate and delay-doppler measurements?

I found this interesting, though it may not be entirely useful: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20080045414/downloads/20080045414.pdf - after upgrades, JPL were invited to carry out an independent assessment of the STEREO orbit determination.
